# Run WSL 2 on a Virtual Machine through vmware fusion

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to install wsl2 in my w10 virtual machine running through VMWare fusion on a mac.

I followed the official guide : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

but when it come to install unbuntu I have this issue :

```
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
Error: 0x80370102 The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

Press any key to continue...
```

Referring to the doc :
Installation failed with error 0x80070003 or error 0x80370102

```
Please make sure that virtualization is enabled inside of your computer's BIOS.
The instructions on how to do this will vary from computer to computer,
and will most likely be under CPU related options.
```

Looks like I have to activate the virtualization on the bios ... but I'm on VM in VM Ware. I went in the VM bios but no such option.

Any idea ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

Under "Processors & Memory" -> "Advanced Options" in the VM Settings menu, check the box "Enable hypervisor applications in this virtual machine".  That did the trick for me with VMWare Fusion 11 and I was able to run WSL2 in Windows 10 / 20H2.

Answer (score 1):

You virtual machine cpu should set using cpu virtualize engine. please see the created vm setting in the vmware menu